# How to prove Matsumura, Appendix A, Tensors, Formula 7?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let all tensors be tensor products of $A$-modules or the tensoring of two functions $f\otimes g : M\otimes N \to M' \otimes N'$ where $f: M \to M', \ g : N \to N'$ are two $A$-module homs.

> *Formula 7*. Suppose given exact sequences
> $$0 \to K \xrightarrow{i} M \xrightarrow{f}M' \to 0 \text{ and } 0 \to L \xrightarrow{j} N \xrightarrow{g} N' \to 0$$
> then $M' \otimes N' \simeq (M \otimes N)/T$, where $T = (i \otimes 1)(K \otimes N) + (1 \otimes j) (M \otimes L)$.

I know that the map $f\otimes g$ is surjective by the exactness at $M', N'$ of the two sequences.  So I merely need to show that $T = \ker f \otimes g$, where $\ker f \otimes g = $ the submodule of $M\otimes N$ generated by all $x\otimes y$ such that $f(x) = 0$ or $g(y) = 0$.

It's easy for me to see that $T$ must be a submodule of $\ker f \otimes g$, and since $f\otimes g$ is generated by simple tensors, that in order to show the reverse inclusion, I need to show that $x \otimes y \in T$ for any simple tensor $x \otimes y \in M \otimes N$ such that $f(x) = 0$ or $g(y) = 0$.

---

Can we find two simple tensors $k \otimes n \in K \otimes N$ and $m \otimes l \in M \otimes L$ such that $i(k)\otimes n + l \otimes j(m) = x \otimes y$?

I thought that would be the easiest to solve for if it indeed had a solution.  Although, it's still not obvious to me what we should try to put for $k,n,l,m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is probably to use the universal property of $M' \otimes N'$ as a tensor product.  Since the kernel $K$ of the $A$-linear map $f \otimes g: M \otimes N \rightarrow M' \otimes N'$ contains $T$, there is an obvious induced $A$-linear map

$$\alpha: (M \otimes N)/T \rightarrow M' \otimes N'.$$

What is less straightforward is to show that there exists an $A$-linear map going in the opposite direction

$$\beta: M' \otimes N' \rightarrow (M \otimes N)/T$$

such that the composition in each direction is the identity.  This will imply that $\alpha$ is an isomorphism and that the kernel of $f \otimes g$ is exactly $T$.

To define $\beta$, define an $A$-bilinear map

$$\mathcal B: M' \times N' \rightarrow (M \otimes N)/T$$

as follows: given $(m',n') \in M' \times N'$, choose $m \in M$ and $n \in N$ such that $f(m) = m'$ and $g(n) = n'$.  Then set

$$\mathcal B(m',n') = m \otimes n + T.$$

It is not difficult to see that this is well defined, and therefore induces an $A$-linear map $\beta$ of the type suggested above.  It is defined on elementary tensors by

$$\beta(f(m) \otimes g(n) ) = m \otimes n + T.$$

Comment: So we extend $\beta$ on simple tensors homomorphically to reach the full summation definition?  In my deleted answer, you are right!  I forgot that the kernel is *generated* by those elements and not equal to the set of those elements.  Your answer is very clear and concise, thank you!  Can we just skip defining $\mathcal{B}$ and say define $\beta$ like so?

Comment: Not really.  Because the expression of an element of $M' \otimes N"$ as a sum of elementary tensors is highly nonunique, you really need to construct the bilinear form on $M' \times N'$ first to ensure that $\beta$ is well defined.